# Keras model with 2 different channel inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I input two images as the input of a model at once, but the two images have different channels.

How to adjust the conv_base input_shape so that it can process two images with different channels simultaneously?

I tried to delete or modify conv_base input_shape but not work.

```
conv_base = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(
weights=None, include_top=False, input_shape=(299,299,None)) #adjust input_shape
conv_base.trainable = True
for layers in conv_base.layers[:-20]:
    conv_base.trainable = False

input_1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))
input_2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(299, 299, 1))
x_1 = conv_base(input_1)
x_2 = conv_base(input_2)


x_1 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x_1)
x_2 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x_2)
x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x_1, x_2])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')(x)
```

Comment: You could just stack the images for a `input_shape` of `(299, 299, 4)`.

Comment: I have to train them separately.

Comment: In the docs it is stated that the `input_shape` should have exactly 3 channels (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/inception_resnet_v2/InceptionResNetV2), so you could just repeat (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/repeat) the last axis from `(299, 299, 1)` to `(299, 299, 3)`, where the last axis is 3x the same. Not sure it will work good, but then the network could work with both images. I did this in one of my projects with an image and got good results.

Comment: If one of your images is grayscale/binary (1 channel) you can convert it to RGB (3 channels) before feeding it to the network.

Comment: convert to RGB and tf.repeat are same ,right?
I will try it .thank you